# android cursor list and activity

Tags: android, cursor

i have a ListActivity to show an Arraylist.
In the onListItemClick() i call another ListActivity.
I have a specific class to extends SQLiteOpenHelper() to manage db.

In the first ListActivity i have this code

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
  secondListActivity itemsList= new secondListActivity();
  itemsList.showItemsList(selection);
  //Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The showComicsList() method in the secondListActivity have

```
public void showItemsList(String name)
{
  DatabasesManager databaseHelper = new DatabasesManager(this);
  Cursor series = databaseHelper.getItemsIdByName(name);
  Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getChildren(series.getString(0));

  for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
    //fetching from database and adding to arrayList
    results.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChildrensTable.NUMBER)));
  }

  cursor.close();

  //display in screen
  this.setListAdapter(
    new ArrayAdapter<Object>(
      secondListActivity.this,
      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
      results
    )
  );
}
```

the getItemsIdByName() call a cursor

```
public Cursor getItemsIdByName(String name)
{
  return( getReadableDatabase().query(
  itemsTable.TABLE_NAME, 
  null, 
  "name =" + name,
  null, 
  null,
  null, 
  null, 
  null));
}
```

When i call the getItemsIdByName() i get this error

```
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at zepod.whatelsecomics.databases.wecDatabasesManager.getComics(wecDatabasesManager.java:159)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at zepod.whatelsecomics.WhatelsecomicsListActivity.showComicsList(WhatelsecomicsListActivity.java:25)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at zepod.whatelsecomics.WhatelsecomicsActivity.onListItemClick(WhatelsecomicsActivity.java:47)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1800)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-12 14:12:17.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: call `databaseHelper.open()` after declaration.

Comment: when i paste databaseHelper.open() the ide say me that i need ti create a open method in databasehelper

Comment: oh, then edit your question and show us your `DatabaseHelper.java` code, you definately have to create a method `open()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely the `context` on your secondListActivity is not set since you are just instantiating it normally without using `startActivity`

This is the line that I assume where you are instantiating your second list (where your `context`  is null):

```
 secondListActivity itemsList= new secondListActivity();
```

If you follow this stacktrace:

> android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)

In the [Android source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#ContextWrapper), you will see that line 203 is

```
  return mBase.openOrCreateDatabase(name, mode, factory);
```

Where `mBase` is the context that you set in `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

In your code, assuming `DatabasesManager` is the one who will interact with `SQLiteOpenHelper`, it is likely `this` that you pass to it is null

```
// "this" is possibly null
DatabasesManager databaseHelper = new DatabasesManager(this);
Cursor series = databaseHelper.getItemsIdByName(name);
```

If you want to use second list in the same Activity, you should consider using the `ListView` directly in the code without wrapping it using the another `ListActivity`